# IsEmpty returns False when target is multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

just curious about if I selected more than 1 cell, let's say 5, then the return from isempty is false. I am wondering why? I understand I could use other method to identify the empty cells. But I simply want to understand deeper about 'isempty' function and 'target' in selectionchange event. Thanks for your help. cheers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right in the documentation...

> False is always returned if expression contains more than one variable.

[IsEmpty function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function)

---

Here is a function that should do what you are expecting it to do:

```
Function AreAllEmpty(Target As Range) As Boolean
  Dim r As Range

  For Each r In Target
    If Not IsEmpty(r) Then
      AreAllEmpty = False
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
  AreAllEmpty = True

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  MsgBox AreAllEmpty(Target)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So may I believe I can never use isempty to identify multi-cells' empty status?

Comment: That would be my assumption, yes. You could write your own routine (`AreAllEmpty(Target As Range)` maybe?) that parses each cell's value using that function if you like tho, and have it return `True` if all of them are Empty, but as it stands, processing multiple expressions is not what the `IsEmpty` function is intended for.

Comment: I provided the function for you to use.